# How to setup config links capistrano3?

Tags: php, capistrano3, vtiger

I'm using capistrano3 to deploy a vtiger project i want to void having passwords in GitHub repo so what i want is to have directory `/opt/vtiger/config/config.inc.php` all the configuration and in some way that I can't figure out link all that `/opt/vtiger/config/config.inc.php` config to `/var/www/vtiger/current/` any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way is to add `config.inc.php` to `linked_files` in your capistrano configuration, and then add `/var/www/vtiger/shared/config.inc.php` as a symlink to `/opt/vtiger/config/config.inc.php`.